# In ceylon, how do I get Class object from a class?

Tags: ceylon

I have a method that takes a `java.lang.Class` object as a parameter. How do I get that from a Ceylon class?

That is, the equivalent of `SomeClass.class` in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `SomeClass.class`, use a meta literal: `` `SomeClass` `` for a closed model, `` `class SomeClass` `` for the open declaration.

For `someInstance.class`, you can use the `type` function from `ceylon.language.meta`.

```
import ceylon.language.meta { type }

class C() {}
class D() extends C() {}

shared void run() {
    C c = D();
    print(type(c));
}
```

[Try it!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=f58c3fe519af92c8056a8331eaf151d6)

(`type` returns a closed model, i. e. with type arguments applied; you can get the open declaration with `.declaration`.)

Comment: This will not return a `java.lang.Class`, though. You'll need to use `javaClass`, `javaClassFromDeclaration`, `javaClassFromModel` or `javaClassFromInstance` from [ceylon.interop.java](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/interop/java/1.3.2/module-doc/api/index.html) for that.

Comment: Yes, but the OP asked specifically for _"equivalent of `SomeClass.class` in java"_. I take it to mean that the OP was interested in Ceylon metaprogramming facilities

Comment: He also says "a method that takes a java.lang.Class object as a parameter" :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for elaborate answer and tips in comments!